# Read CSV size of 4GB or more

Tags: java, csv, jar

I am working on a project, Where they share all data in CSV file, For fast reading of CSV data we using OpenCSV , This works fine till a limit but when I have CSV with a size of 4GB or more, it takes time & many time crash . 
Is there any other way for faster CSV readinder lib or code ???

Answer (score 2):

[This comparison](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) should give you a better idea of which parsers are out there and how fast they can get.

In your case your program is probably slowing down because you are collecting all rows in a List or something of the kind. That's not really a good idea if you can help it.

Using [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) you can try something like this:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(); // or configure the format manually as required

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
for(String[] row : parser.iterate(new File("/path/to/your.csv"), "UTF-8")){
    // your code here
}
```

If you are doing conversions and stuff, you can use `Record` instead:

```
for(Record record : parser.iterateRecords(new File("/path/to/your.csv"), "UTF-8")){
    Long someLongValue = record.getLong("someColumnName");
    BigDecimal someBigDecimalValue = record.getBigDecimal("anotherColumnName");
    // ... etc
}
```

Either way, you should be able to process your file in a few seconds.

Just make sure you are not storing all rows in memory. You can use this library to read a file of 100TB with just 100MB of memory, but if you start storing stuff in lists the garbage collector will kick in and slow you down trying to release memory to avoid an `OutOfMemoryError`. If you really need to have everything in memory, then use `-Xms8G -Xmx8G` or something appropriate to your case.

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer, I'm the author of univocity-parsers - It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

1. What's stopping you from doing this.

   ```
   public void readCsv(final String fileName) throws IOException {

   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
   String strLine;
   while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   processLine(strLine);
   }
   bufferedReader.close();
   }


   private void processLine(final String line) {
   // your code here
   }
   ```
2. You can also look at [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/). It seems like a good use-case.
3. You can also use Executor Framework to process each of your lines in separate threads.